# What would the World Series schedule be in this case?

Tags: baseball, mlb

If the Yankees played the Mets in the World Series, it would be the two teams with the shortest distance between ballparks.

As it is now, and for every other case in memory, there is a travel day where games are not played as the series shifts from city to city.

In this example, since the Series is being held in the home city for both teams, would there be a travel day between switches in home stadiums, or would the series play out in 7 days?

Comment: As late as 1979, no travel day was scheduled even for the move from Baltimore to Pittsburgh between Games 2 and 3, though there was a travel day for the move back to Baltimore before Game 6. The 1971 series between the same teams did have the expected travel days, though Game 2 was delayed by rain until the travel day without postponing Games 3, 4, or 5.

Comment: The last intracity series prior to 2000 appears to have been 1956 between the Yankees and then Brooklyn Dodgers. There don't appear to have been any scheduled off-days, though Games 2 through 6 were played on consecutive days after Game 2 was originally postponed due to rain.

Comment: @chepner  Excellent finds

Comment: Lots of other interesting close pairs, but I stopped when I realized I was going off on quite a tangent. For example, 1985 KC/STL, 1983 PHI/BAL, 1989 OAK/SF (which appeared to have a single "travel" day after Game 2 replaced by an earthquake week, and then the series ended in a 4-game sweep anyway).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This already happened. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2000_World_Series
You can see from the link that they had the usual travel day between games 2 and 3. Note that MLB schedules these things way in advance so the TV networks can plan around them, so they won't change just because two teams are in the same city.